# VBA to click a button on a website and extract tables

Tags: html, vba, parsing, excel

I want to click a button on a website with VBA and extract the table which appears when clicked.

My code is here but it is not working right now, how can I do that?

I want to click the "Get Price Quoted" button on the right corner of the table and extract appearing information.

```html
Sub Test()



Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String
   Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

strURL = "http://financials.morningstar.com/competitors/industry-peer.action?t=GOOG&region=usa&culture=en-US"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
     .Visible = True
     .navigate strURL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Dim Item As Object
    Set Item = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("hspacer0")
    Item.Item(0).Click

      Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        
            Set doc = IE.document
            GetAllTables6 doc

            .Quit
        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clicking the correct button the code. I am not sure what button if any you are clicking. But if you run the javascript code loadIndustryPeersQuoteData(1) it will 'click' the button and then you will need to code getting the table.

That 'hspacer0' is just a blank spacer that contains no objects or anything to click.